# Canvas alignment issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, canvas

I'd like to generate a field that displays `NxN`squares. *(In the example it displays 2x2 red squares)* in the center of the canvas. The field where the squares are located in should be horizontally & vertically centered in the canvas. (Also after changing rowCount for sure)

Moreover fieldSize declares the size of the calculated area where the red squares are aligned in. Changing the factor will change the fields Size. (*1 == canvas Size, 0.5 = 1/2 canvas Size*)

---

My question:

In the example below (it is hard to see) the red boxes aren't really centered but I'd like them to be. Have a look at this image:

[image]

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")


/* edit these values */
let rowCount = 2
let fieldSize = canvas.width * 0.8
/********************/


let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

for (let y = 0; y < rowCount; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < rowCount; x++) {

    let squareSize = (fieldSize / rowCount) * 0.7

    let positionX = (fieldSize / rowCount) * (x) + (canvas.width - fieldSize) * 0.5
    let positionY = (fieldSize / rowCount) * (y) + (canvas.width - fieldSize) * 0.5

    ctx.rect(positionX, positionY, squareSize, squareSize);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red"
    ctx.fill()
  }

}
```

```html
<canvas style="background: green" id="canvas" width="300" height="300" id="codeCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that way (it works for any amount of rows) :

```
(canvas.width - fieldSize) / 2)
```

is for the padding of the field

```
x * (fieldSize / rowCount)
```

is for the relative position of each square

```
(fieldSize / rowCount - squareSize) / 2
```

is for the padding of each square and that is missing in your code

```js
/* edit these values */
let rowCount = 2
let fieldSize = canvas.width * 0.8
let squareSize = (fieldSize / rowCount) * 0.8
/********************/


let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

for (let y = 0; y < rowCount; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < rowCount; x++) {

        let positionX = (canvas.width - fieldSize) / 2 + x * (fieldSize / rowCount) + (fieldSize / rowCount - squareSize) / 2
        let positionY = (canvas.width - fieldSize) / 2 + y * (fieldSize / rowCount) + (fieldSize / rowCount - squareSize) / 2

        ctx.rect(positionX, positionY, squareSize, squareSize);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red"
        ctx.fill()
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas style="background: green" id="canvas" width="300" height="300" id="codeCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the "inner space" without padding and spread your squares on that. 
Due to rounding issues, you are not free to use all combinations of padding/spacing. To produce a prefect grid, you will have to use discrete square sizes to prevent aliasing or blurring effects.

```js
function tiled(canvas, rowCount) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const spacing = 10;
  const padding = 30;
  const cellSize = (canvas.width - 2 * padding + spacing) / rowCount;
  const squareSize = cellSize - spacing;

  let positionX = padding;
  let positionY = padding;

  for (let y = 0; y < rowCount; y++) {
    positionX = padding;
    for (let x = 0; x < rowCount; x++) {
      ctx.rect(positionX, positionY, squareSize, squareSize);
      ctx.fillStyle = "red"
      ctx.fill();
      positionX += cellSize;
    }
    positionY += cellSize;
  }
}

tiled(document.getElementById("canvas"), 2);
tiled(document.getElementById("canvas2"), 3);
tiled(document.getElementById("canvas3"), 4);
tiled(document.getElementById("canvas4"), 5);
```

```html
<canvas style="background: green" id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas style="background: green" id="canvas2" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas style="background: green" id="canvas3" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas style="background: green" id="canvas4" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Also looks like a really nice solution. But theres also the problem of the missing property for the fields size. Would you be so kind to edit?

Comment: Implicit the fieldSize is there, it is `canvas.width - 2*padding` or, the padding is `0.5*(canvas.width - fieldSize)`

Answer (score 0):

This might help !

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")

/* edit these values */
let rowCount = 2
let fieldSize = canvas.width * 0.8
/********************/

let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

let width = canvas.width;
let height = canvas.height;

let dist = canvas.width/(rowCount + 1)

for(let i=1;i<=rowCount;i++){
  for(let j=1;j<=rowCount;j++){
  let w = (fieldSize / rowCount) * 0.8
    let posx = dist*i - w/2;
    let posy = dist*j - w/2;
    ctx.rect(posx,posy,w,w);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas style="background: green" id="canvas" width="300" height="300" id="codeCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Looks like a really nice solution. Thanks so much. But it looks like the fieldSize property is not working anymore. (You should be able to specify the size in which area the squares are located like 0.8 as factor of the canvas width. Would you mind to update your solution?